# Mercurial server setup on Windows with apache and hgweb.wsgi

Tags: windows, mercurial, wsgi, hgweb

my first post here and looking for advice. For a couple of days now I have been trying to get a Mercurial server up and running at my work. But I am failing miserably with the same errors. For reasons beyond my control it has to be accessed through Apache.

I currently have:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Apache 2.2
- Python 2.7
- Mercurial 2.7.2
- A locally held repository for testing (in C:\Repositories\repo1)
- mod_wsgi

My hgweb.config and hgweb.wsgi are in C:\Repositories and, along with httpd.conf, look like this:

hgweb.config

```
[paths]
/ = C:/Repositories/*

[web]
style = coal
push_ssl = false
```

hgweb.wsgi

```
config = "C:\Repositories\hgweb.config"
#import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial")
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mercurial")
from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb
application = hgweb(config)
```

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName hg.example.net
    ServerAdmin me@myplace.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Repositories"
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog C:/Repositories/error_log
    CustomLog C:/Repositories/access_log common
    LogLevel debug

    WSGIScriptAlias  /hg  "C:/Repositories/hgweb.wsgi"
    #WSGIScriptAlias  /  "C:/Repositories/Hello World.wsgi"

    <Directory C:/Repositories>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all      
        AllowOverride All
        AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The simple Hello World.wsgi works fine, which suggests to me that Apache, Python and mod_wsgi are all playing nicely together. But whenever I use hgweb.wsgi I get an internal server error... contact me@myplace.com... Which although not working does imply that it is at least reading and using the ServerAdmin in httpd.conf

The error.log states that hgweb.wsgi can't be loaded as a Python module (output below stripped of date, ip, etc.):

```
mod_wsgi (pid=4764): Target WSGI script 'C:/Repositories/hgweb.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=4764): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Repositories/hgweb.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Repositories/hgweb.wsgi", line 19, in <module>
    application = hgweb(config)
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\hgweb\\__init__.py", line 26, in hgweb
    return hgwebdir_mod.hgwebdir(config, baseui=baseui)
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\hgweb\\hgwebdir_mod.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\hgweb\\hgwebdir_mod.py", line 98, in refresh
    u = ui.ui()
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\ui.py", line 45, in __init__
    for f in scmutil.rcpath():
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\demandimport.py", line 86, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\demandimport.py", line 58, in _load
    mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\scmutil.py", line 274, in <module>
    class vfs(abstractvfs):
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\scmutil.py", line 302, in vfs
    @util.propertycache
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\demandimport.py", line 86, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\demandimport.py", line 58, in _load
    mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\util.py", line 27, in <module>
    cachestat = platform.cachestat
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\demandimport.py", line 86, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\demandimport.py", line 58, in _load
    mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\windows.py", line 36, in <module>
    posixfile.__doc__ = osutil.posixfile.__doc__
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\demandimport.py", line 86, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mercurial\\demandimport.py", line 58, in _load
    mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Any help or ideas would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If at all possible, Try HgLab (which I am the author of): http://hglabhq.com/

Comment: Spent half a day on fighting issues with apache denying access to the wsgi script on windows. Turns out all the documentation including posts like this one are using Apache 2.2 configs and 2.4 uses different config for controlling this.